# Is there a process for creating a Microsoft word toolbar button that can insert a pre-made grouped shape or pre-formatted table?

Tags: vba, templates, ms-word, toolbar

Hello my organization uses Microsoft word for a lot of standard reports. For part of a process a stamp gets placed on the cover during review. Is there a way to use a tool bar button that will automatically insert the stamp? The stamp is a grouped object including graphics and an editable table.

[Stamp Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lpi2G.jpg)

I looked in the customize toolbar menu under options but the only thing I could think of is to create a macro that would grab the object. The issue is how can I get a macro to insert a grouped object?

Comment: Hi, this is a programming forum, not a Word forum. Your question is ***off-topic*** here and likely will be closed without answers. The confusion is understandable. https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  This would be an appropriate question on the **Microsoft Community** https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_word This is really not a programming question but a Word question. See https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/create-and-choose-from-multiple-stamps/d9ed6efd-56f1-42ff-a56d-766464c6cf9a and https://addbalance.com/word/download.htm#DateStamp

Comment: Again, not a programming question. If it were a programming question you would need to give us your code to check. What you want can easily be part of a building block in Word and inserted with a QAT button or a keyboard shortcut. Ask about this in a Word forum.